# Map Vs. Mapping?

Tags: terminology

I am so confused in the usage of the words: Map and Mapping.

For example, consider **the mapping**: $T:W^{2,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow L^{p}(\Omega)$ defined by $T(u):=\Delta u.$ Can we write: consider **the map** $T$ in this case? When do we use map? and mapping?

Thanks.

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: So they can be used interchangeably in any case?

Comment: Yes, the choice is yours!

Answer (score 9):

While they strictly mean different things, they are often used synonymously by most people, just like we abuse language elsewhere. For example, when we say consider the function $f(x),$ which strictly speaking is not a function, but an expression; more over, since we have not specified the domain or codomain. But this is often used and doesn't cause much confusion.

Similarly here. Although the word **map** refers to the **image of the mapping,** while the word **mapping** is synonymous with **function, transformation, and similar words**; we often use them interchangeably without real confusion. It reminds me of the use of transformation/transform in a similar cavalier way in the theory of integral transforms. The transformation or mapping is different from its product, the transform or map, but we often identify the function $f:A\to B$ with its image $f(x),$ where $x\in A.$

In other words, **the mapping is the operation,** whereas **the map is the product** of the operation. However, just like we usually identify a function and an expression embodying its image, we usually identify a mapping and the map embodying its image, without serious confusion.

---

To apply this to your example, what would be most appropriately called the **map** is $T(u),$ whereas $T$ is most properly called the **mapping**. But few people bother about these distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am not a native speaker, I would like to oppose the answer of Allawonder.
In differential geometry we have "chart" $h$ from open subset of a manifold to some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I would call the range of a mapping T "the map" of M rather than $T(m)$ for some particular $m \in M$.

$\mbox{ran}(T)=\{y:\exists x: \langle x,y\rangle\in T\}$

Usual use case is, for example, "the world map", which is given below, certainly is about the range. You can "pick a point on a map", so it is some set, rather than a particular element.

[image]